# Generate unique name everytime like "Windows folder structure" behaviour

Tags: objective-c

I want to create folder structure logic like windows.I am using SQlite database for that. I want to generate a unique name everytime. For e.g. if user enters text with name "New". And if again he enter same name "New" then it should be New(1).  if again he enter same name "New" then it should be "New(2)". If user delete "New(1)" entry and enter "New" then "New(1)" should be placed in between "New" and "New(2)".

Could anyone suggest logic for that? Any help is appreciated?
Thanks in advance
Tejas

Comment: you will store folder names in database no?

Answer (score 0):

I consider you will have a database with id and foldername as fields. You just need to retrieve all records from database. In where of query use [like](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator. Once you get list go in a loop and add add new entry by comparing number. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the logic I use to do something similar in an app:

1. Declare an `NSString` called `prefix` and an `NSInteger` called `number`.
2. Check if your name has a number on the end of it:

   - If it does, set `number` to the value of that number and `prefix` to the name without the number.
   - If it does not, set `number` to 1 and `prefix` to the name.
3. Loop from 1 up to some maximum number, doing the following:

   1. Construct a `proposedName` from base and number:

      - If `number` is 1, use the bare `prefix`.
      - Otherwise, concatenate the `prefix` and `number` in the format you're looking to generate.
   2. Check if `proposedName` is already in use.*

      - If it is in use, increment `number` and loop again.
      - If it is not in use, `proposedName` is your new name.

Given that you're using a SQLite database, you can probably speed this up a bit by pre-fetching names that begin with your prefix and loading them into an `NSMutableSet`. That'll be faster than performing a query for each individual name.

* When you do this test, you should probably exclude the object you're already looking at. This will allow you to try to "uniquify" the name of an existing object without actually changing it.